# How to fit a bitmap to a random size rect so it does not strech? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, graphics, android-studio

I'm trying to fit a bitmap to a random size rect but I don't want the bitmap to be streched out. I've tried using BitmapShader and tile it but it become animated and not fixed.

Here is my code without BitmapShader.

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      canvas.drawBitmap(spike1, null, rectangle, paint);
      canvas.drawBitmap(spike1, null, rectangle2, paint);
 }
```

Here is my code with BitmapShader.

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(spike1, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, paint);
}
```

Here is a picture of my problems
[image: Here is a picture of my problems]

Can somebody tell what I need to do so the image is fix but not stretched?

Comment: You probably shouldn't repeat the texture vertically

Comment: their are 3 options, mirror, clamp and tile and none of them works. I also try not passing anything vertically but it's the same thing. :-l